# Unable to send email via PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to connect to `smtp.google.com` for sending emails but the SMTP ports are blocked by network admin.

How can I get around this problem. Please Help.

Comment: Perhaps tell this to your administrator ?

Comment: This would actually be a very uncommon setup. It is very rare that _outgoing_ requests are blocked by a local firewall. Certainly possible from a technical point of view, but not trivial. If this really is the case, then there must be a very severe reason for that.

Comment: You could ask your system administrator to open these ports.

Comment: Actually outbound blocking is very common - in particular GoDaddy does it. The workaround is to use your ISPs mail server - they usually have docs on that.

Answer (score 0):

If the SMTP ports are blocked by the network admin, you will have to contact your administrator.
You can not fix this by changing your code.